# printing out elements that are not in both HashSets

Tags: java, set, hashset

I don't want to enter the whole code (I feel it's unnecessary). My problem is: I have two big strings that I split by ';' and add to two Hashsets. Having that, I want to check if the elements of both sets are the same and if they're not - print out different elements. I don't want to make it by any iteration because the corresponding elements are to be the same so there's no need to iterate through every element.

```
    Set latestStableRevConfigurationSet = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(latestStableRevConfiguration.split(";")));
    Set currentRevConfigurationSet = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(currentRevConfiguration.split(";")));

    assertTrue(latestStableRevConfigurationSet.containsAll(currentRevConfigurationSet));
    assertTrue(currentRevConfigurationSet.containsAll(latestStableRevConfigurationSet));
```

The way above I can only assert if the sets are 'the same' but how to implement a A-B/B-A so printing out different elements?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    Set<String> latestStableRevConfigurationCopy = new HashSet<>(latestStableRevConfigurationSet); 
    Set currentRevConfigurationCopy = currentRevConfigurationSet; 

    latestStableRevConfigurationCopy.removeAll(currentRevConfigurationSet );
    currentRevConfigurationCopy.removeAll(latestStableRevConfigurationSet );

    //this would print all the different elements from both the sets.
    System.out.println(latestStableRevConfigurationCopy );
    System.out.println(currentRevConfigurationCopy );
```

Comment: `currentRevConfigurationCopy`is no copy of `currentRevConfigurationSet`: it's just another reference to the same set!

Comment: Yes, I know. I just named it as **currentRevConfigurationCopy** for easy understanding.

Comment: One should still be aware that the original `currentRevConfigurationSet` has been modified, in case it is to be used again. To be safe from side effects one should take a copy like you did for `latestStableRevConfigurationSet`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Guava:

```
SetView<Number> difference = com.google.common.collect.Sets.symmetricDifference(set2, set1);
```

If you don't want to add new dependecy, you can slightly modify code available on [Github](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Sets.java) repo.

Answer (score 1):

You want all the elements that are only in one set. A way to do that is to take the union of all the elements with

```
Set union = new HashSet();
union.addAll(latestStableRevConfigurationSet);
union.addAll(currentRevConfigurationSet);
```

and then take the intersection (i.e. the common elements)

```
Set intersection = new HashSet();
intersection.addAll(latestStableRevConfigurationSet);
intersection.retainAll(currentRevConfigurationSet);
```

and finally subtract the two:

```
union.removeAll(intersection);
```

Comment: It's unnecessarily complex. Don't invent the wheel for the second time!

Comment: That's why I upvoted your answer! I completely agree that it's better to use a library that already does this, but still it can be useful to see how it can be done without introducing (possibly) a new dependency.